# Did Peter Jackson (or his production team) explain why Legolas' eyes changed color between The LoTR and The Hobbit?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

In Peter Jackson's *The Fellowship of the Ring*, *The Two Towers*, and *The Return of the King* Orlando Bloom's Legolas has brown eyes (much as the actor portraying him does, although I am unsure if the specific brown was altered with lenses or CGI):

[image: Legolas' brown eyes in The Fellowship of the Ring]

But in *The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug*, Orlando Bloom is wearing ice blue contact lenses (or perhaps this is done in CGI).

[image: Legolas' ice blue eyes in The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug]

Has Peter Jackson or his production team explained why this discrepancy exists between the two productions? I find the difference quite jarring when Legolas appears in *The Hobbit* films.

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69385/is-it-because-the-time-gap-that-legolass-eyes-are-different-in-hobbit-and-lotr